# SQL Server 2012 Intellisense issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

My problem is that Intellisense does not provide complete auto suggest for the columns that I have in my tables .

Here is an example:

[image: sql 2012]

As you can see on SSMS it does give me auto suggest for my tables, but does not for columns. I have read couple articles about solving some Intellisense issues, but nothing helped. Here is things I tried described in this article: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2591/troubleshooting-intellisense-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012/

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time!

Comment: In your example above do you have a table name populated in the `FROM` clause already?  I only get column suggestions when it knows what table to suggest them from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliSense can't predict which table you're going to select from, and will wait until you have at least one table in the FROM clause, and probably only until you specify an `alias.` before populating the columns in the case of a join or other multi-table query.

There's a good reason for this. Imagine if you have `CustomerID` or `InvoiceID` in 20 different tables in your database. Should it list this 20 times? Which one should you pick? Do you really want *all* the columns in your entire database in a drop-down list? In a lot of scenarios this will be a *very long* list. And not pretty either, in things like SharePoint, NAV Dynamics, etc.

If you're not happy with the way the native IntelliSense works, there are 3rd party tools that might do what you want, but I'm not sure what you want will actually help you work any better.

Answer (score 0):

First, that's because at the time of the screenshot SSMS does not know from what object you are selecting. In other words, it cannot guess what columns you're interested in when there is not a `from` clause in your `select` statement. If you try to type in the columns in the following `select` statement...

```
select from dbo.Invoices
```

you will see that SSMS will start to pick up your columns because you have already specified a `from` clause, so SSMS knows how to suggest you column names...because there is a table specified in the `from` clause

Answer (score -1):

This is mainly occurs when you add any table in the Database OR Add any Column in the Table.
This is the known issue of the SQL Server 2012. You need to refresh the Cache for that.

---

You can achieve using 2 ways..

1) You can Refresh the Local Cache of the IntelliSense.

Open New Query window and Navigate to following menu.

Edit > IntelliSense > Refresh Local Cache

Shortcut key for this is (Ctrl + Shift + R)

2) ReConnect Your Database.